# German idiom for "in so.'s infinite wisdom"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, idiom, phrase-request

I want to translate (something like) the following:

> Chris, **in his infinite wisdom**, has...

In English, *in so.’s infinite wisdom* is a sarcastic way of saying that you think what someone did was stupid.

Would the correct translation be something like:

> **In seiner unendlichen Weisheit** hat Chris...

or is this untranslatable, in which case, is there another German idiom which means something similar?

Comment: Is it really sarcasm or rather "irony"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is sarcasm, @user20884, but if you can draw up some stuff (dictionary definitions) as to why it could be irony, that'd be great!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*In seiner unendlichen Weisheit* is correct and idiomatic, i.e., it is actually used by native speakers. However, there are two other idiomatic alternatives you might want to consider:

- ***In seiner nicht enden wollenden Weisheit**: Nicht enden wollend*  liteally means *not wanting to end* and thus the phrase almost means the same as your suggestion. The slight difference is that *nicht enden wollend* implies that Chris’ has a history of doing stupid things – his current action demonstrates that he is yet undepleted as a source of <s>wisdom</s> stupidity.
- ***[Die Weisheit mit Löffeln fressen](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Weisheit+mit+L%C3%B6ffeln+fressen)**:* This literally means *to eat wisdom with spoons.* It can be used ironically and non-ironical (in which case it is often negated). Temporally, you first eat the wisdom and then act because of it. You might use it in your example sentence as follows:

  > Chris hat die Weisheit mit Löffeln gefressen: Er hat …
  >
  > Chris, der die Weisheit mit Löffeln gefressen hat(te), hat …

Comment: Personally, I’d prefer another variant: _in seiner/ihrer unergründlichen Weisheit_. It is less common than _unendlich_ according to Google, though.

Comment: @chirlu: Why don’t you make it another answer?

Comment: Does using 'hatte' instead of 'hat' change the meaning subtly? I might guess that 'hatte' implies that this *particular* action was stupid, whereas 'hat' would mean that this person has a track record of doing stupid things.

Comment: @digitalis_: Without further context: no. I don’t want to exclude the possibility of a context where it does make a difference, but I cannot think of one right now.

Comment: Another variant is "unermessliche Weisheit".

Answer (score 6):

"In seiner unendlichen Weisheit" is exactly correct and expresses the intended sarcasm.